# What I'm missing in my system?

Tags: qt4

I'm writing an application with QT4. At the moment I have installed OpenSuse 11.4 x86_64. I need to build an application for 32-bit platform because one of my included libraries has been compiled in this version.

In qt-Creator, build options, I set parameter: `-spec linux-g++-32`.

```
g++ -m32 -o Faktura main.o mainwindow.o timer.o QueryAtlasFactory.o 
            MySqlQueryAtlas.o  moc_querythread.o moc_printthread.o 
            qrc_zasoby.o    
         -L/usr/lib64 /home/neon/workspace/qt4/Faktura/drukarki/elzab/elzabdr.a 
         -lQtSql -L/usr/lib64 
         -lQtGui 
         -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lQtCore 
         -lpthread
```

Unfortunately, the compiler is linking 64-bit libraries and returning errors:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libQtSql.so when searching for -lQtSql
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../libQtSql.so when searching for -lQtSql
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so when searching for -lQtGui
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../libQtGui.so when searching for -lQtGui
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libQtCore.so when searching for -lQtCore
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../libQtCore.so when searching for -lQtCore
```

List of qt4 packages installed in my system: `rpm -qa *qt*`

```
libqt4-sql-mysql-4.7.1-7.2.x86_64
libqt4-devel-doc-data-4.7.1-7.1.noarch
kdevelop4-pg-qt-devel-0.9.0-3.1.x86_64
mono-qt-4.6.0-3.4.x86_64
libqt4-sql-32bit-4.7.1-7.1.x86_64
yast2-qt-pkg-2.20.3-3.1.x86_64
vlc-qt-1.1.8-1.pm.2.4.x86_64
libqt4-4.7.1-7.1.x86_64
libqt4-sql-mysql-32bit-4.7.1-7.2.x86_64
qtcurve-gtk2-32bit-1.8.1-3.1.x86_64
yast2-qt-2.20.4-1.2.1.x86_64
libqt4-devel-doc-4.7.1-7.3.x86_64
mono-qt-devel-4.6.0-3.4.x86_64
qt4-x11-tools-4.7.1-7.3.x86_64
libqt4-devel-4.7.1-7.1.x86_64
libqt4-sql-4.7.1-7.1.x86_64
libqt4-sql-sqlite-4.7.1-7.1.x86_64
libpackagekit-qt14-0.6.12-1.4.1.x86_64
python-qt4-4.8.3-3.2.x86_64
yast2-qt-graph-2.19.0-4.1.x86_64
qt-creator-2.1.0-1.3.1.x86_64
libqt4-qt3support-32bit-4.7.1-7.1.x86_64
libqt4-x11-4.7.1-7.1.x86_64
libpoppler-qt4-3-0.14.4-6.1.x86_64
libdbusmenu-qt2-0.6.6-3.1.x86_64
yast2-control-center-qt-2.20.2-1.3.1.x86_64
libqt4-x11-32bit-4.7.1-7.1.x86_64
qtcurve-gtk2-1.8.1-3.1.x86_64
kdevelop4-pg-qt-0.9.0-3.1.x86_64
qt4-qtscript-0.1.0-10.1.x86_64
libqt4-sql-unixODBC-4.7.1-7.2.x86_64
libqt4-sql-sqlite-32bit-4.7.1-7.1.x86_64
libqt4-32bit-4.7.1-7.1.x86_64
libpolkit-qt-1-1-0.99.1-5.1.x86_64
qt4-qtscript-doc-0.1.0-10.1.x86_64
libqt4-sql-unixODBC-32bit-4.7.1-7.2.x86_64
patterns-openSUSE-devel_qt4-11.4-6.9.1.x86_64
libqt4-qt3support-4.7.1-7.1.x86_64
pinentry-qt4-0.8.0-8.1.x86_64
```

Question is: what I'm missing in my system to build 32-bit app, or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What about `-L/usr/lib32` or `-L/usr/lib` instead of `-L/usr/lib64`?

Comment: This -L/usr/lib64 has been linked automatically by linker. Build parameter -spec linux-g++-32 should fix it, but it isn't.

Comment: What do you mean by _it has been added by linker_? This is the link command! Check your IDE to change those link directories.

Comment: I put -L/usr/lib into build options. Still the same issue.